# NullPointerException in Smack XMPP client when trying to connect to FCM endpoint

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, xmpp

Im trying to connect to Firebase XMPP endpoint to receive upstream messages. Im using Java Openfire Smack library. But I dont know what to put into server domain. Im always receiving this error. I tried to find some example of using this library and firebase, but i wasnt able to find some.

Source that I used for endpoint:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.jivesoftware.smack.util.dns.DNSResolver.lookupHostAddress(org.minidns.dnsname.DnsName, java.util.List, org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration$DnssecMode)" because the return value of "org.jivesoftware.smack.util.DNSUtil.getDNSResolver()" is null
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.rce.RemoteXmppTcpConnectionEndpoints.lookup(RemoteXmppTcpConnectionEndpoints.java:71)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPTCPConnection.java:591)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectInternal(XMPPTCPConnection.java:849)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.connect(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:526)
    at XmppClientModule.run(XmppClientModule.java:38)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

This is my connection config.

```
    private static final String fcmServer = "fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com";
    private static final int fcmPort = 5236;
    private static final String fcmSenderId = "101010101010@fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com";
    private static final String fcmApiKey = "XXX";
    private XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration configuration;
    private XMPPTCPConnection connection;

    public XmppClientModule() {
        try {
            configuration = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                    .setUsernameAndPassword(fcmSenderId, fcmApiKey)
                    .setXmppDomain("fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com")
                    .setHost(fcmServer)
                    .setPort(fcmPort)
                    .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.required)
                    .build();

        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error handling");
        }

        connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configuration);

    }
```

My dependencies

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.2'

    implementation 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-core:4.4.6'
    implementation 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.4.6'
    implementation 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.4.6'
    implementation 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-xmlparser-xpp3:4.4.6'
}
```

Comment: I think that is maybe caused by the missing smack-java dependency.

Answer (score 0):

As Flow said in comments i missed this dependency:

```
implementation 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-resolver-dnsjava:4.4.6'
```